# Microsoft Bot Application Template not appear on Visual Studio 2015 Update 1/2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, botframework

I have tried to follow instructions about Microsoft Bot Connector ( http://docs.botframework.com/connector/getstarted/#navtitle ) on Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition version 14.0.25123.00 .Net Framework 4.6.01038, with update 1 then 2, the zip archive has been stored in appropriate folder “%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#" Unfortunately, the associated template does not appear in "Installed / Visual C#" category, on attempt to create a new project. Is it possible to provide any support and/or recommendations?
Thx,

Comment: you just copied the zip, right? didn't try to unpack it? it needs to be in zip form in that directory.

Comment: also, have you restarted vs?

Comment: yes, vs has been restarted

Answer (score 17):

If you look in Visual Studio 2015 settings under

Tools
   Options
       Projects & Solutions
            User project templates location

You can see where Visual Studio is looking for templates.  Our docs specified for the most common location, but it may be unique on your machine.

--jim

Comment: jim you are right.One reason for not finding the templates could be if visual studio is looking for one drive location.  "C:\Users\Prath\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#". This location could be different based on settings.

Answer (score 2):

Mine wasn't working, turns out it was on my ***\\network\redirected roaming \mydocs\username***\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#

If you have roaming documents it will save to the network not the C:\users\

Answer (score 1):

> **here is a good document and the steps all at one go !  How to install  Microsoft Bot framework : 
>   1.    Download bot template from Microsoft sdk https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/gettingstarted.html
>   2.    Follow the guid lines to install your visual studio template, in a general place such as  %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#\
>   3.    Start visual studio and see if it appears in templates under Visual C#
>   4.    If it does not, follow the below steps.
>   4.1.  Open visual studo => Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions
>   4.2.   Go to the user templates location 
>   4.3.  Right click on the zip -> Properties ->unblocking , select the check box. 
>   4.4.  Close visual studio if its open and reopen visual studio**

https://sway.com/MOj75VsDStzwpBD0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please avoid using answers containing only links or content directly copied from links. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/315457

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, but my %USERPROFILE%\Documents folder is on my D: drive.  I had to install the zip template into the equivalent path on my C: drive before it would appear in Visual Studio.

Comment: "Bot Application" zip file has been stored in C:\Users\achan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#\  The zip file is still present, I have no other zip files in this directory, it does not appear in VS2015 installed templates

Comment: Is the zip unblocked?  Right-click to open properties and select the checkbox to unblock.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one drive configured, it will be in your one drive folder. "C:\Users\\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates"
Try it out!